# Why are vaccines a successful treatment of allergy?

Tags: immunology, medicine, immune-system, antigen, allergies

As I understand the answer to [Allergic rhinitis vaccine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/17951/33294), the vaccine facilitates immune response against the antigen.

Given that allergy is an overreaction of the immune system against harmless antigens, how can facilitation of the immune response act as a cure (moderate the response or so)?

Comment: This is basic and also broad. I see you read this question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30195/5198. Though it is not the same question, it does provide the answer. See also a possible duplicate: [How Do White Blood Cells Learn? Or Do They?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30102/5198)

Comment: @anongoodnurse Indeed, I had read the linked questions. Don't get me wrong, but I think one of us is misinterpreting written text again. Why do you think questions about **facilitation** of the immune response against a **pathogen** address **moderation** of the response against an **allergen**?

Comment: "...how can facilitation of the immune response act as a cure?" There is no mendion of moderation of the immune response in your question. That is a different (and also broad) question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse ok, now it is stated explicitly

Comment: Still basic (first question) and now too broad.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I definitely miss your point. I am not a native speaker, but IMHO there are two question marks, but only one question. Also I can not address the breadth issue.
Let's assume I am not clever enough, so unless you wish to devote a lot of time to explain it, I propose to drop the conversation. The question has been already interpreted as intended and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory is that constant and gradual escalation of the administered dose of allergen eventually tolerizes the immune system to the allergen through the induction of peripheral Tregs or IL-10-secreting effectors.

While the purpose of a traditional vaccine against a pathogen is usually to rile up the immune system with and adjuvant or modulators, the idea of allergy immunotherapy is to sensitize the patient to the problematic allergen by implementing chronic exposutre. That mechanism is still poorly understand and is not thought to have immune memory, as the effects of the therapy tail off after discontinuation.